# Loading Jade -> HTML via Websockets + NodeJS instead of AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, node.js, websocket, pug

Wondering if there's a clean correct way to load html markup through websockets instead of through a $.ajax({...}) request. I'm somewhat new to websockets so I'm trying to figure out where it can completely replace AJAX and so on...

Right now I just create another 'post' router in my NodeJS app to load the html but I don't know if all of that is even neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

you need websockets mostly if you want to maintain a bidirectional connection between client and server, useful for real-time applications (like chats, stock marketing, e-learning etc.).

if you need to load html mark down, you don't need to go back and forth from client to server many times to load the content and serve it, it will be much elegant and not wasteful way.

you can also use to get route and $.get ajax requests if you do not want to pass additional payload to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you can pass data through websockets to your client from the Node.js server and, once on the client, just post it to the page.

If you are using socket.io, for example, you can emit an event inside your server with your generated html which will be received at client code:

On the server:

```
socket.emit('yourFiringEvent', variableContainingYourRawHtml);
```

On the javascript client:

```
socket.on('yourFiringEvent', function(htmlResult) {
    $("#yourContainerId").html(htmlResult); //jQuery flavour ;-)
});
```

When your client code receives the event from server will load the data on *variableContainingYourRawHtml* inside of *HtmlResult*

If you aren't using it I recommend the use of socket.io library for websocket use, it's quite powerful and easy:

http://socket.io/

Comment: But how would you get it from a jade file, to raw html from within node?